# Binding a stack to a TreeView in reverse order using converter

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, stack

I have designed a class that allows binding a stack to a TreeView and everything works great except I need to display the collection in reverse.

This is the code for my Stack class:

```
public class Stack<T> : BindingList<T>, ICloneable
{
    #region Methods

    public void Push(T item)
    {
        this.Add(item);
    }
    public T Peek()
    {
        if (this.Count > 0)
        {
            T temp = this[this.Count - 1];
            return temp;
        }
        else
            return default(T);
    }
    public T Pop()
    {
        if (this.Count > 0)
        {
            T temp = this[this.Count - 1];
            this.RemoveAt(this.Count - 1);
            return temp;
        }
        else
            return default(T);
    }
    public ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection()
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> o = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        foreach (T t in this)
        {
            o.Add(t);
        }
        return o;
    }
    public List<T> ToList()
    {
        return this.ToList<T>();
    }
    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    #endregion

    public Stack() {
    }
}
```

And I bind like so:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ListToBind}"/>
```

How can you reverse the order of the items automatically using a converter?

Comment: How about creating new collection with reverse order and binding? Like `var reversed = new Stack<T>(ListToBind);` ?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. If you have two different question, post them as two different questions. Re: sorting: you can either wrap your collection in a new collection that is always the reverse of the original (e.g. updating when the wrapped collection is updated), or you can wrap your collection in a collection that includes an element index and then sort descending your view of the wrapper collection on the element index. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried.